# Can I create a new immersive view while in a scene in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I have a native (c++) code that creates an immersive view for HoloLens 2. I have a wrapper for this in order to use that in Unity. What I want to do is I want to call my immersiveView.init() function when a button is clicked in my Unity app, and switch to the immersive view it's created. I have tried that but when the native code requests a thread in order to initialize the immersive view, it does not get allocated, I cannot get the result. I think it may be impossible to create an immersive view while I am in a scene in Unity, which is also an immersive view but I am not quite sure

Comment: Would you share more details about immersiveView.init() or your c++ code? The requirement is not clear. Do you want to load holographic objects additively?

Comment: It calls the following:
`auto holographicSpace =  winrt::Windows::Graphics::Holographic::HolographicSpace::CreateForCoreWindow(window);`

Comment: How do you get the "window" that is used by CreateForCoreWindow()? It is not a common scenario because this should be done more easily by creating a separate app as it is stated at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/app-views#2d-views.

Comment: `auto window = UI_Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();` is the way that we get the window